# Can I change the current year of bsDatepicker?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, visual-studio, ngx-bootstrap

In my typescript code I am just importing the => { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

I have this html codel:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
  <input type="text"
        placeholder="Datepicker"
        class="form-control"
        bsDatepicker>
 </div>
```

The result is:
[what I have.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEnU8.png)

I want the basic calendar to begging form 2004.
Something like: [what I want.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZfid.png)

How can I change the first year that pops-out to be 2004 instead of 2020?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can use `date: '01-01-2004'`

Comment: you can just click on year and it gives you option of new year values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no value set for the datepicker it will default to the current date. This is what you see happening in your example.

What you can do is inside the html template add the `[bsValue]="dateForDatepicker"` attribute to your `bsDatepicker` input element.

```html
  <input type="text"
        placeholder="Datepicker"
        class="form-control"
        bsDatepicker
        [bsValue]="dateForDatepicker"
  >
```

In the component you can then add `dateForDatepicker = new Date("01-01-2014")` which should cause the datepicker to display that value initially.

For more information you can check the documentation: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#date-initial-state